# postgres last 10 working days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to select rows which are within last 10 working days. Working days are assumed to be dates when rows are present.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: No sample data is required for this question. The question is self explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply take the last ten days, using something like this:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.date in (select t2.date
                 from table t2
                 group by t2.date
                 order by t2.date desc
                 limit 10
                );
```

An alternative is to use the `dense_rank()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by date desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Both of these assume that the date column has no time component.  Removing the time component is a trivial adjustment to either version.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from your_table where your_table.date_field >= current_date - interval '10' day;
```

Replace `your_table` with your table name, and `date_field` with the date field and have fun.